# XOAUTH2 Invalid SASL argument in Django

Tags: python, django, gmail, imap

I create Django project and in this project i have one moment, it authenticate in `gmail` by `XOAUTH2`. This code work local(if i create python project and run it):

```
is_authenticate = False
    imap_conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host='imap.gmail.com', port=993)
    imap_conn.debug = 4
    try:
        imap_conn.authenticate(mechanism='XOAUTH2', authobject=lambda x: auth_string)
        is_authenticate = True
    except BaseException as e:
        print(e)

    return is_authenticate
```

but in django project i have exception:

> AUTHENTICATE command error: BAD [b'Invalid SASL argument.
>   n1mb22847377ltj']

this is debug information:

```
  06:55.79 > b'HLKK1 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2'
  06:55.86 < b'+ '
  06:55.86 write literal size 304
  06:56.05 < b'+ eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ=='
  06:56.05 write literal size 304
  06:56.24 < b'HLKK1 BAD Invalid SASL argument. n1mb22847377ltj'
  06:56.24 BAD response: b'Invalid SASL argument. n1mb22847377ltj'
```

Comment: What do you see when it does work?

Comment: If you decode the response with base64, you get the JSON document: {"status":"400","schemes":"Bearer","scope":"https://mail.google.com/"}  I don't know what status 400 means though.

Comment: Potentially means expired Access Token.

Answer (score 1):

When you called

```
imap_conn.authenticate(mechanism='XOAUTH2', authobject=lambda x: auth_string)
```

the `auth_string` value / your `authobject` function must not do any base64 encoding. The underlying `imaplib` library does the base64 for you.